# Looking for "localhost" apache server that allows .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

Is there some apache server software out there that can be installed on my Windows PC (for local development purposes) that also allows .htaccess for URL rewriting?

I'm currently using Xampp which does not seem to offer this functionality (although maybe I'm wrong about that).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to activate mod_rewrite in your apache config. Go to your xampp folder an you will find the httpd.conf file in apache/conf/. Open it an go to the line with:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Change it to

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Save the httpd.conf and restart your apache. Now mod_rewrite should work.

Answer (score 1):

Xampp will do it, you'll need to enable mod_rewrite first.

open the directory you installed Xampp then open \apache\conf\httpd.conf in notepad and search for mod_rewrite.

Uncomment the line by removing the # from the beginning. By default mod_rewrite is disabled on a fresh install.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Restart Xamppp should take .htaccess rules now.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that by default, Xampp on windows does not support URL rewriting.
However it's an pretty easy fix:

1. In your httpd.conf file, find the line that contains "mod_rewrite" and remove the # in front of it
2. Again in your httpd.conf file, find all occurrences of AllowOverride None and change it to AllowOverride All
3. Restart apache and you're done:)